# Algorithm for matrix multiplication with using representative vectors

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

As exercise for a course I have to convert a lower triangular matrix to a vector, example [a 0; b d] -> [a b d]. After that I have to write an algorithm in `MATLAB` that would do the matrix multiplication only using vector mode.

Can any body help me with the algorithm?

Comment: You mean that you take a MxN matrix and a NxM matrix reshape them both to (MxN, 1) and then you want to perform the 'right' matrix multiplication? Is the former matrix dimension known? Because i have no idea if its even possible when the former dimension is unknown. If it is known you can just loop through your data to get the right result. Therefor you should look at the definition of matrix multiplication and where those elements end up after your transformation.

Comment: matrix multiplication of two such lower triangular matrices in their vector modes?

Comment: Also if it's lower triangular shouldn't it be `[a 0;b d]`?

Comment: And you need to keep the 0 inside your vector form, otherwise you won't know which element is to be left out.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the form your right it should be [a 0;b d]. And we know the size of the original matrix. However we cannot include 0 in our vector form to save space. So the vector should be in a form: [a b d]. We cant convert the vector to matrix for multiplication and operations should be made only on the vectors. We have to define new multiplication operator that takes two vectors and gives a vector which is a multiplication of original matrix. For example give [a 0; b d]^2 = [a 0;ab+bd bd]. We have to convert the matrix to vector [a b d] * [a b d] = [a ab+bd bd].

Comment: I think thats impossible. Since the 4 matrices: `[0 b; a d]`, `[a 0; b d]`, `[a b; 0 d]` and `[a d; b 0]` all result in `[a b d]` vector. So you definetely need to keep the 0s inside your vector. Also how would you want to diferentiate between a 3x3 matrix with only 3 non zero elements and a 2x2 matrix with one 0? the vectors would be the same length and therefor should be computable. If you say you got your previous matrix dimension and your transformed vectors. Just loop through the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here my code which works if the zeros stay inside your vector. No idea if there is a way to solve your question if the zeros don't stay in your vector.

```
mytest_Mat1 = round(rand(3,4)*10);
mytest_Mat2 = round(rand(4,5)*10);
mysize_Mat1 = size(mytest_Mat1);
mysize_Mat2 = size(mytest_Mat2);
if mysize_Mat1(2)==mysize_Mat2(1)
mytest_vec1= reshape(mytest_Mat1,1, mysize_Mat1(1)*mysize_Mat1(2));
mytest_vec2= reshape(mytest_Mat2,1, mysize_Mat2(1)*mysize_Mat2(2));
mytest_result = zeros(1,mysize_Mat1(1)*mysize_Mat2(2));
for m=1:mysize_Mat1(1)
   for n=1:mysize_Mat2(2)
        mytest_helper =0;
        for o=1:mysize_Mat1(2)
            mytest_helper = (mytest_helper+mytest_vec1(m+(o-1)*mysize_Mat1(1))*mytest_vec2((n-1)*mysize_Mat2(1)+o));            
        end
        mytest_result((n-1)*mysize_Mat1(1)+m)= mytest_helper;
   end
end
mytest_MatMult = mytest_Mat1*mytest_Mat2
mytest_result
else mytest_error = ('The dimensions of the matrix do not fit!')
end
```

The `mytest_helper` computes the elements which are finaly saved in `mytest_result`.